# Best solution for deleting elements from a list array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

So, i have an array, of a custom type, used in Angular :

```
List {
    task: string;
    id?: number;
    status?: boolean;
}
```

Here, I want to delete elements that have `List.status == true` I tried 2 methods for this, the first one is very simple, it requires `.filter()` :

```
return listArray.filter(item => !item.status);
```

The problem of this method, is that even though it returns the list with need elements deleted, after modifying the array, it reverts to it's sate before editing + added element, so I came to second method, it is quite longer, and requires both .filter() and .forEach() :

```
listArray1.filter(item => !item.status).forEach(item => {
listArray2.filter((element, index) => {
    if (element === item) {
        listArray2.splice(index, 1);
    }
});
```

Is there a possible way to make this method shorter, or is there another method that will also work in angular?

Comment: why not do this `listArray = listArray.filter(item => !item.status);`

Comment: Because, it troubleshoots in Angular. Yes, it modifies the array, but when i add new elements to it, than the array reverts to it's state before .filter()

Comment: Here I showed only the object's structure, the array is declared as `ListArray: List[]`

Comment: where are you doing this?

Comment: you can also use `_.remove` in lodash

Answer (score 1):

For those who wants to use [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#without) can use: myArray = _.without(myArray, itemToRemove)

for use in angular use like bellow:

```
import { without } from 'lodash';
...
myArray = without(myArray, itemToRemove);
...
```